# Median from NumPy and DataFrame are differently evaluated

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

Why do Pandas and NumPy treat their evaluation differently for some basic functions like the median?

Pandas automatically omits NaN values, NumPy does not.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(10)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10), columns=['x'])
df.loc[df.x > 1, 'x'] = np.NaN

print(df)

#     x
#0  NaN
#1  NaN
#2  0.0
#3  1.0
#4  NaN
#5  0.0
#6  1.0
#7  NaN
#8  NaN
#9  0.0

print(df['x'].median())

#0.0

print(np.median(df['x']))

#nan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are 2 different libraries. They use different conventions/defaults.

If you want to ignore the NaN:

```
np.nanmedian(df['x'])
df['x'].median()
```

If you want to have a NaN result:

```
np.median(df['x'])
df['x'].median(skipna=False)
```